Etiquette on accepting answers
What are the rules of etiquette (the culture) on accepting answers?
I certainly don't want to leave the impression that I don't care about the answers on my questions. I feel it would be boorish to ask and then not care about the answers.
It has been suggested to me to accept answers and I feel pressured by it. The most recent case was in the Main Site of Engineering.SE but it has also happened in other sites like Economics etc. I hope the question is fine here and it isn't migrated to Meta.SE.
To showcase the most recent case and illustrate my confusion.
How are NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens designed differently?
Here Demis gave me an answer which earnestly confused me.
In the META where I asked first if I could ask the question they confirmed what I see in the Picture
NanoledTM Electroluminescent Quantum Dot Display.
I thought their comment meant that the difference was that Microleds were Photoluminescent and Nanoleds were Electroluminescent. Althought I was not clear on that. I can't understand how Photoluminescent Microleds could be Self-Emissive.
Then on the answer on the actual question on the Main site they state

The term NanoLED appears to be a marketing term, not a technical term,
don't let it confuse you.

Which is a complete opposite of what they said earlier.
If NanoLED is a marketing term not a technical term the answer could be much shorter and could use much more definite wording (without "appears" and other words that show wavering and diffidence).
I am earnestly confused and I don't feel the answer "solves" my problem, that it explains the difference bettwen Microled and Nanoled.
So what is the Etiquette on accepting answers; what should I do in cases where I feel pressured to accept the answer but I don't feel my question was answered?
